# Avoid replicating whole tables in Matlab `join`'s

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a table T of records and fields.  I want to create a new field and populate it with the result of a lookup of another table L.  This means that I will use one or more fields in T as a foreign key.  In SQL, I can UPDATE the newly created field in table T using a JOIN with table L. Conversely, Matlab has no updating of an existing table when doing a `join`; that creates a whole new table, which is then used to replace the original table T.  It seems like a lot of data replication to populate one field.  Is this avoided under-the-hood?  Is there a code design pattern or idiom that avoids this, but is still reasonably readable and doesn't compromise on code compactness too much?

While I asked this question in the context of `join`, I'd be interested in general in strategies for avoiding table replication in all variations of Matlab joins.

I'll describe an example of how, for each record in `Table1`, the `ForeignKey` is used to look up `Data` in `Table2`.

```
        Table1
-----------------------------
SomeField NewField ForeignKey
--------- -------- ----------
someData1 dummy    a
someData2 dummy    b
someData3 dummy    a
someData4 dummy    b
someData5 dummy    a

Table2
--------
Key Data
--- ----
a   apple
b   banana
```

The following SQL code performs the lookup.  The entry in the `Data` field is then concatenated with the content of field `SomeField` in `Table1` and stored into field `NewField`.

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ForeignKey = Table2.Key
SET Table1.NewField = Table1.SomeField & Table2.Data
```

The updated `Table1` is:

```
        Table1
------------------------------------
SomeField NewField        ForeignKey
--------- --------------- ----------
someData1 someData1apple  a
someData2 someData2banana b
someData3 someData3apple  a
someData4 someData4banana b
someData5 someData5apple  a
```

Interesting to note that `Table INNER JOIN Table2` isn't actually created.  It is only "virtually" created to enable the calculation with which to update `Table1`.  In contrast, Matlab's `JOIN` creates the actual joined table, and a separate operation is needed to do the calculation.

Comment: Could you give an example for what type of query you'd do with this `join`? I think you might want to work differently with MATLAB tables that with SQL tables. An example would help me figure out what to suggest.

Comment: Done.  Thanks for prompting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation that you're doing must look something like this:

```
table1 = table({'someData1';'someData2';'someData3';'someData4';'someData5'},...
   {'a';'b';'a';'b';'a'},'VariableNames',{'SomeField','ForeignKey'});
table2 = table({'a';'b'},{'apple';'banana'},'VariableNames',{'Key','Data'});

table3 = join(table1,table2,'LeftKeys','ForeignKey','RightKeys','Key')
```

This produces the following table:

```
 SomeField     ForeignKey      Data  
___________    __________    ________

'someData1'    'a'           'apple' 
'someData2'    'b'           'banana'
'someData3'    'a'           'apple' 
'someData4'    'b'           'banana'
'someData5'    'a'           'apple'
```

And then you are applying some sort of operation on the columns `SomeField` and `Data`.

I think this `join` function has been added to make use easy for those familiar with SQL but less familiar with MATLAB syntax.

If you are still worried about copying large amounts of data (as I mentioned, this is not the case because of lazy copying), you can obtain the column `Data` above using the following set-based operations:

```
[~,index] = ismember(table1.ForeignKey,table2.Key);
data = table2.Data(index);
```

Here, `data` is a cell array, identical to `table3.Data`. In any case, the `index` values created here are what SQL would create internally for this JOIN operation. If a `table1.ForeignKey` is not in `table2.Key`, the corresponding `index` value is 0 (MATLAB indexes starting at 1). In that case, you cannot use `index` directly to index, you would need to use an additional level of indexing to get only the valid rows:

```
[valid,index] = ismember(table1.ForeignKey,table2.Key);
data1 = table1.SomeField(valid)
data2 = table2.Data(index(valid));
```

Note that `table/join` uses `ismember` in this exact same way, then copies the left table (which causes the copy to reference the data in the input table due to lazy copying), and adds columns to it for the right table.

Comment: Thank you again, Cris, for that very insightful description of what happens under the hood of `join`.  I've gotten so use to imagining the complete result of `Table1 INNER JOIN Table2`, with the `SELECT` clause filtering the resulting columns, that I lost track of the fact that the whole `JOIN` isn't actually created, and neither does it have to be created, even in Matlab (using `LeftVariables` and `RightVariables` Named Pairs).

Comment: As for `ismember`, I've used it in past years, but not the `index` output, which is like a steroid enhanced vectorized lookup.  So powerful for those wanting to poke below the `join` command.  I really miss being able to ignore the details of how queries are actually implemented below the SQL level but given the choice of wrestling with the cruft of interfacing to Access versus poking below the SQL level in Matlab, I still think the latter is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

I’m no expert on tables, but I can give insight into how MATLAB operates with this type of data.

A MATLAB `table` object contains a matrix for each column.

Copying a matrix in MATLAB does not copy the data. MATLAB uses lazy copying. This means that the copy references the same data as the original (until the copy or original is changed, at which point a copy is made). This behavior is well documented [(1)](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/), [(2)](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations).

Thus, creating a new table using **whole** columns from other tables would cause matrices to be copied, but these copies don’t incur any actual copying of matrix contents, the new table references data in the original tables.

But if any of the values in a column is changed, the whole column will need to be copied to avoid the other table to see the same change. The reference is internal and temporary, and invisible to the user. For all intends and purposes, it looks like the new table contains a copy of the original data.

However, if the `join` operation causes rows to be swapped or removed, all of this is a moot point. The data will be copied.

Comment: Cris, I was aware that Matlab uses lazy copy whe passing arguments to functions, but not when updating tables.  Would it be accurate to summarize your answer as saying that entire tables don't get replicated, but the columns/variables that are changed do get copied?

Comment: @user36800: each column is a matrix, so if you change one value, the whole column must be copied (if it’s shared).

Comment: Note also that `table` is a `classdef` style object, you can examine the source code to verify what I’m saying here.

Comment: I re-read your explanation.  It sounds like references to the original column data need to be tracked so that Matlab knows when a copy must be made in response to a change in the data.  In your 1st paragraph, when you say "until the copy it original is changed", do you mean "until the copy *or* original is changed"?

Comment: As for delving into the implementation code for `table` methods, I'm still trying to get to know the gotchas for `splitapply`.  I generally try to avoid diving into the insides of native constructs because I just get lost.  Even if I figure out how things work, and designed-for behaviour, I can't assume that it will persist unless it's formalized in the help page.  Mind you, the other side of the coin is that there are often holes and errors in the documentation, and documentation doesn't prevent TMW from changing the designed-for behaviour.  But to be fair, TWM documentation is quite good.

Comment: @user36800: "until the copy or original is changed", indeed. Fixed the typo. Matlab tracks copies of all arrays. This is not something inherent to tables, it is built into the way that arrays work. I've added some links you might find interesting. However, reading your question again, I came to realize that `join` would not necessarily just copy over whole columns unchanged, so this answer might not be relevant at all to you. I tried reading `edit table/join`, but can't make much sense of it.

Comment: Thanks, Cris.  I'm not sure what you mean by `edit table/join', but the documentation for `join` reveals it to be quite flexible in the kind of result generated.  The left table argument is the base table, while the right table argument is the lookup table.  Hence, the ordering of records is based on the left table.  I have yet to play around extensively but it seems possible for the results table to include any number of columns from the left and/or right table.

Comment: The columns from the left table won't change their row order, so based on your explanation of reference copying of unchanged columns, they will likely simply be reference copies of the data in the left table. Conversely, the columns formed by looking up data from the right table aren't really columns from the right table, as they don't necessarily even have the same height. So those columns will be assembled from scratch. That's not redundant copying of columns, but rather, synthesis of columns from lookup data.

Comment: BTW, I figured out what you meant by `edit table/join`.  I never use `edit` myself (vim's my go-to editor), but from the Matlab m-file editor, II can extract the m-file path and call it up in vim (with a bit of mussing to change the DOS path separators into UNIX separators).